# Azure DevOps artifact linking format

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When we link GitHub commit or PR to Azure Bords, it comes in specific format.

```
{
            "rel": "ArtifactLink",
            "url": "vstfs:///GitHub/Commit/db85e178-2e4e-4bb2-beda-7b448a02e219%2f5b957b13416ebb207be6ce0bf04054b29e14f3a1",
            "attributes": {                
                "name": "GitHub Commit"
            }
        }
```

can anyone let me know what it contains in the URL placed below? I understand that highlighted one is the commit id. what is the other part before %2F?

"url": "vstfs:///GitHub/Commit/db85e178-2e4e-4bb2-beda-7b448a02e219%2f**5b957b13416ebb207be6ce0bf04054b29e14f3a1**",

Answer (score 1):

the following URL is a VSTFS link to a GitHub commit in the repository with the ID db85e178-2e4e-4bb2-beda-7b448a02e219:

`vstfs:///GitHub/Commit/{repo ID}%2F{commit ID}`

Comment: not able to identify this as a repo ID. 
I couldn't find this repo id using below API
https://api.github.com/users/{USER_ID}/repos